# Automatic spacing adjust in Python

Tags: python

I have a `Python` code with a mixture of 2 and 4 spacing. I would like to make it consistent. Is there any software that can

- automatically adjust to a consistent spacing
- ideally, it can adjust for a given range of lines, e.g., 1-300. So I can test the adjustment segment by segment
- Linux or Windows platform

An example of a code with mixed spacing

```
n = 2
m = 3
for i in range(n):
  for j in range(m):
    print(i, j)

for i in range(n + 1):
    for j in range(m + 2):
        print(i, j)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`reindent` can at least adjust to all 4 spaces
https://pypi.org/project/reindent/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).